# CheckAll checkbox for Datatable with Search

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

In the table (that show items from database) we have a column to delete items and checkbox to select them all.

It's done by this simple code :

Here is example of html for delete checkbox cell :

```
<td>
    <a href="/item/delete/2"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="2" id="delete_item2" class="delete_item">
</td>
```

And here is javascript part :

```
$('#checkAll').click(function() {
if($('#checkAll').is(":checked"))
    $('.delete_item').prop('checked', true);
else
    $('.delete_item').prop('checked', false);
});
```

It works globally fine, except that we also use DataTable functionalities and especially Search function.

The problem is that with actual code user could search some lines of table, but if he click "Check All" it will select (and so probably delete) all the rows of the table (even not visible).

Normally it seems easy to fix, we just need apply `$('.delete_item').prop('checked', true);` only for visible rows (probably via `{search:'applied'}`) but I could not figure how to do it.

**Update :**

As supposed @mark_b in the comments the behavior should be different as I explain.

After testing on fiddle and checking once again the application js code, I found that it's true. The real application code is a little bit different from one that I put in the question example.

Once I remove this little difference, the behavior become correct. The "Check All" checkbox select only visible row.
So the problem is solved.

I don't know if this question should be removed... For the moment I leave it here with this Update.

Comment: If you use the developer tools of the browser, you should find a difference of the attributes for the not visible rows - for example ``display: none``. Which one is it?

Comment: "probably delete) all the rows of the table (even not visible)" - Are you sure that's the case? Have you tested it? Rows on other pages are not even in the DOM. Also your first code block is going to generate duplicate `id`s

Comment: @biberman : thanks for suggestion. I didn't think this way, as I saw that "{search:'applied'}" should be used to address "searched" rows. But it's a good try to see how it's done using dev-tools.

Comment: @mark_b : yes, I'm pretty sure. It's the actual behavior in our application. But you are right, I'll probably create a little fiddle to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @mark_b : and why the first block will have same id. First block it's not a template, it's a real html. So in the template I do id in form `delete_item<item_id>`, so in my example it's `delete_item2` as it's item #2.

Comment: @mark_b : you are absolutely right. I create a fiddle and the behavior is not the same as I explain, it select only visible rows. In fact in the application javascript is a little bit different. And it's this small difference that make all the row to be selected. Putting exactly the same code as in the question solved the problem. Thank you very much.